# C# formatting excel column with epplus as negative number with prentices

Tags: c#, epplus

I am trying to get an column formatted as a number. I want it with 1000 separator and red prentices. I am using Epplus 5.7.5 and C# .net 4.72
Some reason it just ignores this formatting.

```
workSheet.Column(4).Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0 ;[Red](#,##0)";
```

Comment: By _prentices_, do you mean _parentheses_ (i.e., `(parentheses)`)

Comment: @flydog57 - an apprentice will be in charge of formatting the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself. The only issue with this is if you have a large amount of data formatting the individual cell will slow down the export.

```
private static void CreateData(ExcelWorksheet workSheet, ref int rowIndex, DataTable dt)
    {
        int colIndex = 0;
        int intNumberCheck = 0;

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) // Adding Data into rows
        {
            colIndex = 1;
            rowIndex++;

            foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            {
                var cell = workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex];

                bool isNumber = Int32.TryParse(dr[dc.ColumnName], out intNumberCheck);

                if (isNumber == true)
                {
                    //Setting Value in cell
                    
                    cell.Value = Convert.ToInt32(dr[dc.ColumnName]);
                    cell.Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0 ;[Red](#,##0)";
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    //Setting Value in cell
                    cell.Value = Convert.ToString(dr[dc.ColumnName]).Trim();
                }

                colIndex++;

            }
        }

        dt.Dispose();
    }
```